# Objective c - trouble with Archiving encode and decode

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I am learning objective-c at the moment and up to the archiving and got stuck with encode and decode.

here is my code.

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Foo : NSObject<NSCoding>

    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *strVal;
    @property int intVal;
    @property float floatVal;

    @end

    #import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo

@synthesize intVal, floatVal, strVal;

-(void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject: strVal forKey: @"test1"];
    [encoder encodeInt: intVal forKey: @"test2"];
    [encoder encodeFloat: floatVal forKey: @"test3"];
}

-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder
{
    strVal = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"test1"];
    intVal = [decoder decodeIntForKey: @"test2"];
    floatVal = [decoder decodeFloatForKey: @"test3"];

    return self;
}

@end


    #import "Foo.h"

    int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        @autoreleasepool {
            Foo *myFoo1 = [[Foo alloc] init];
            Foo *myFoo2;

            [myFoo1 setStrVal : @"bill"];
            [myFoo1 setIntVal : 2];
            [myFoo1 setFloatVal: 3.4];

            [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: myFoo1 toFile: @"foo.arch"];

            myFoo2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: @"foo.arch"];

            NSLog(@"%@", [myFoo2 strVal]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The decode works for int and float, however when i try to decode the NSString object. i got the following error and i have no clue about it...

Thread 1: programe received signal: EXC_BAD_ACESS"

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug 15 16:03:10 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
[Switching to process 2457 thread 0x0]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Comment: Where is your @implementation of `Foo`? It seems you copied main() into your question twice.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer you are right... thanks edit it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-initWithCoder:` is an initialiser method, where you *must* call `[super init]` before setting up your object. See the example in Apple's "[Archives and Seralizations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-97254)".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ARC?

Regardless, you should copy all strings (`strValue = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"test1"] copy];`), in order to keep an immutable reference to them. Otherwise, they can change or disappear behind your back and things will go kaboom (like you're seeing).

Also, like @一二三 said, don't forget to `self = [super init];`.

Comment: Even if you don't copy an `NSString`, it can never just "disappear" (provided you `retain` it); only change its value unexpectedly.

Comment: In the case of the code shown, the given string isn't being retained or copied when set. Also, it's safer to always `-copy`, because you don't know if the object passed in is immutable or not, or how it might change behind your back.